# Private NuGet Server: Request Entity Too Large

Tags: wcf, nuget

We have a internal NuGet server (ASP.net app using the NuGet.Server package) and we want to use it with Octopus to deploy packages.  So the first thing you hit is that the packages are too large.

When you push a package larger than around 7 Meg you get:
Failed to process request. 'Request Entity Too Large'.
The remote server returned an error: (413) Request Entity Too Large..

Based on the documentation on Octopus, I updated the web.config file to have the changes.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="elmah">
            <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah"/>
            <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah"/>
            <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah"/>
            <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah"/>
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
        <httpModules>
            <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah"/>
            <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah"/>
            <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah"/>
        </httpModules>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="419430400" executionTimeout="3600"/>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
            <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
            <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
            <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
        </modules>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".nupkg" mimeType="application/zip"/>
        </staticContent>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="419430400"/>
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
    <elmah>
        <security allowRemoteAccess="false"/>
        <errorLog type="Elmah.XmlFileErrorLog, Elmah" logPath="~/App_Data"/>
    </elmah>
    <location path="elmah.axd" inheritInChildApplications="false">
        <system.web>
            <httpHandlers>
                <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah"/>
            </httpHandlers>
        </system.web>
        <system.webServer>
            <handlers>
                <add name="ELMAH" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
            </handlers>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="apiKey" value="KeyHere"/>
        <add key="packagesPath" value=""/>
    </appSettings>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

That does not work.  Other posts talk about running something like (IIS7):
appcmd.exe set config  -section:system.webServer/serverRuntime /uploadReadAheadSize:"419430400"  /commit:apphost

or (IIS6):
cscript adsutil.vbs set w3svc/1/uploadreadaheadsize 419430400

I tried both to no avail.  Neither command returned an error, so I assume that the value '419430400' is correct for all of the calls (bytes vs. some other unit of size).

Anyone have any idea what I am missing?

I ended up just copying the package to a share on the web server, but I would really like the push command to work.

Comment: I too have done the same steps as @Tyrel and have came to the same end, manually placing the package into the folder.  I want my build server to be able to push packages to the NuGet Server which is on another machine.  I have yet to see a definitive answer to this issue.

Answer (score 35):

Not exactly answering the OP's question, but related to the topic, I was getting the `(413) Request Entity Too Large` error while using `NuGet push` to push to a local SymbolSource server - turned out I was submitting to a slightly incorrect URL, once I corrected the command to point to the base `/NuGet/` URL, it ran just fine.

No idea why an incorrect URL results in the 413 error, but there you go. Hope this helps someone.

EDIT: based on comments below, you may have more luck just referencing the base `http://www.myserver.com/` URL rather than including the /NuGet as well. Worth playing around a bit.

Comment: It helped me! I got this error with the incorrect URL as well. Thanks!

Comment: For my case, I have to remove `/NuGet` and just have the base URL: `http://localhost:56211`

Comment: Like stack247, it only worked when I removed the nuget/ part on the end, so it should look like this:  http://nuget.internalserver.com/NuGetServer/ not http://nuget.internalserver.com/NuGetServer/nuget

Comment: NB: This is a real pain, because Visual Studio (2013 at least) needs the /nuget suffix. This makes it hard/impossible to use nuget.exe and use a configured alias in the -source parameter (eg 'teamcity' rather than 'http:// myteamcityserver:someport/some/other/guff').

Comment: Ah. Worked in out finally. URL required is inconsistent between list/restore and push, which is the root of all the confusion. See my answer below.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old question, but today I was faced with the same error. It's worth noticing that I'm using `TeamCity` package building and publishing. Anyway, when I try to `Publish` my huge package (about 200 MB) I was blocked with this. The solution was simple:

Instead of publishing to `http://mynugetserver/api/v2/`, **use:** `http://mynugetserver/`

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to set these guys to higher values:

- system.web - httpRuntime - maxRequestLength to, say, 1048576
- system.webserver - security - requestFiltering - requestLimits -
  maxAllowedContentLength to, say 1073741824

Both values are in a different unit so the second one should be larger than the first.

Also, have a look at www.myget.org which I found great when working with Octopus Deploy.

Comment: Tyrel already has 419430400 set for the maxRequestLength on the httpRuntime.  That should be waaaay more than enough.  I'm getting this same error with a package that is 120KB.

Answer (score 2):

Check your `serverRuntime` configuration.

The `maxRequestEntityAllowed` and `uploadReadAheadSize` attributes respectively configure limits for the maximum number of bytes allowed in the entity body of a request and the number of bytes a Web server will read into a buffer and pass to an ISAPI extension.

More details: http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/serverruntime

My guess is that you are using `SSL` and setting `uploadReadAheadSize` will solve the issue. Because during client renegotiation process,the request entity body must be preloaded using SSL preload. SSL preload will use the value of the `uploadReadAheadSize` property, which is used for ISAPI extensions.

**Here are the defaults**

```
<location path="Default Web Site"> 
   <system.webServer> 
      <serverRuntime enabled="true" 
         uploadReadAheadSize="49152" 
         maxRequestEntityAllowed="4294967295" /> 
   </system.webServer> 
</location>
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on [@Keith](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17813278/26167) and [@Nubigetter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28901575/26167)'s answers, I did some further research, because the behavior seemed really weird to me.

The answer is actually in the [documentation](https://docs.nuget.org/create/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds#step-5:-deploy-and-run-your-brand-new-package-feed!) for Nuget.Server (if you look *very* carefully), it's just not very obvious:

- use http://mynugetserver/nuget for list/restore
- use http://mynugetserver/ for push

I've raised this with the Nuget team here https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery/issues/2903 because I regard this behavior as 'presenting opportunity for improvement'.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue:

```
[Step 1/2] Publishing package to feed at http://localhost/OctopusDeploy/nuget/packages...
[Step 1/2] Failed to push to package feed at 'http://localhost/OctopusDeploy/nuget/packages/'. 
[Step 1/2] (The server responded with: [413] Request Entity Too Large)
[Step 1/2] Process exited with code 1
```

but the Octopus Deploy service had stopped!

Answer (score 0):

This is due to nginx limitations, the nuget server in Linux system use nginx as proxy and config file under:

```
/etc/nginx/conf.d/nuget.conf

server_name localhost;
root /var/www/public/;
client_max_body_size 200M;
```

change client_max_body_size 200M is working for me.

Answer (score -1):

What worked for me was in this article:

http://blogs.blackmarble.co.uk/blogs/rfennell/post/2012/10/31/403-and-413-errors-when-publishing-to-a-local-Nuget-Server.aspx

"Important: This second error was a red herring, you don't need the /nuget on the end of the URL"

Comment: You don't need the /nuget on the end of the URL *when pushing packages*. You *do* when retrieving them (nuget list etc...). This is in the doco, but... sheesh. Way to confuse everyone.